# Slide Toggle on multiple li using jQuery

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have one UL having 3 Li, There are divs under each LI which are in hidden. I have one span on LI and I want the div to slide out when i click on the individual LI. Please can you help me? Here is the demo jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/jB83e/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like

```
$(".slide").hide();

var tglHandle = $(".icon");

tglHandle.click(function() {
    $(".slide").hide();
    $(this).next(".slide").slideToggle("slow");
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, as you want to just `toggle` the `.slide` div next to the `icon` element.

```
tglHandle.click(function() {
        $(this).next('div.slide').slideToggle("slow");
    });​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/jB83e/6/

Answer (score 0):

I edited the script, changed it to this:

```
$(".slide").hide();

var tglHandle = $(".icon");

    tglHandle.click(function() {
        $(this).next(".slide").slideToggle("slow");
    });​
```

working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H4CcN/)

Answer (score 0):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/jB83e/7/)

```
$(".slide").hide();
$("span").click(function() {
$(this).next().toggle();
});
```